# Why does my correlated subquery never finish?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this

Directory nvarchar(max)
Extension nvarchar(10)
Length bigint

I also have another table that provides the type of file (lookup table)
extension nvarchar(10)
FileType nvarchar(50)

That being said I have a correlated subquery I wanted to migrate to a sproc that takes in the levels from the root and gives you back the directories and their file types at that specific level.  There are about 400k rows in the main table and about 800 extensions in the lookup table.

The query is this:

```
declare @levelsFromRoot as int = 7
--declare @auditName as varchar(max) = 'Aetna'

select
    ef.Type,
    sf.Directory,
    (select count(distinct part)
     FROM dbo.vwAuditView
     cross APPLY dbo.SplitPath( substring([Directory],1,LEN([Directory])

                        -CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Directory]))) ,'\') AS Results
                                where Directory = sf.Directory) as [LevelsFromRoot]
from dbo.FS02V_SourceFiles sf
inner join dbo.ExtensionFix ef
    on sf.Extension = ef.Extension
Where (select count(distinct part)
     FROM dbo.vwAuditView
     cross APPLY dbo.SplitPath( substring([Directory],1,LEN([Directory])

                        -CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Directory]))) ,'\') AS Results
                                where Directory = sf.Directory) = @levelsFromRoot
order by Directory asc
```

The cross apply section in the subquery counts the levels in each path starting from the root.  you should be able to pass in how many levels from the root and pass back a list of directories at that level and their corresponding file types.  This query has already been running 25 minutes.  It is returning data to me.  Is there anything I can do to improve this one?  I'm fairly new at correlated subqueries and figure I am doing something wrong here.

For clarity the view looks like this:

```
select    Directory
        --, ef.Extension
        , ef.Type
        , sum(Length) as [Size - Bytes]
from dbo.FS02V_SourceFiles sf
INNER JOIN dbo.ExtensionFix ef
    on sf.Extension = ef.Extension 
group by ef.type, Directory
```

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CHARINDEX2]
(
    @TargetStr varchar(8000), 
    @SearchedStr varchar(8000), 
    @Occurrence int
)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos INT, @counter INT, @ret INT

    set @pos = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr)
    set @counter = 1

    if @Occurrence = 1 set @ret = @pos
    else
    begin

        while (@counter < @Occurrence)
        begin

            select @ret = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr, @pos + 1)

            set @counter = @counter + 1

            set @pos = @ret

        end

    end

    RETURN @ret
```

Comment: What does your split function look like? Are there while loops or cursors in there? What about the view? I suspect the problem is not really the correlated subquery but because the split function is not a good one and you are calling multiple times.

Comment: @SeanLange - I updated the original answer with the function definition.  Yes there is a while loop in there.  I didn't write the query but it was doing exactly what I needed.  I wanted to pass it a string like 'C:\Foo\Bar' and have it return how many levels from the root - IE 2 - another example 'C:\Foo\Bar\Another' returns 3.  But it should also actually split the string if I chose to ingest the data that way.

Comment: That splitter is very likely the root of your problem. You should consider replacing that with a set based splitter. Here are many great examples. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I will look at your link but right now I just rewrote this function and it worked like a charm.  Query finished in about 18 seconds.  I will take into account your link though as I would like to look at this from a set based approach.  If you made this an answer I would select it for you.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That splitter is very likely the root of your problem. You should consider replacing that with a set based splitter. Here are many great examples. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings